# extending session timeouts

Tags: php, session-cookies, session-timeout

I have a website where users log in, in this website, it wouldn't be strange for them to have a webpage open for hours, maybe even a whole day.

How would i go about keeping their session active for a longer period of time? Could this be done in a script? or would it be a setting on the server? I don't really mind members being logged out and having to log back in, but the people i work with use the control panel and they don't want to be logged out all the time.

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may you have to use the cookies for it in your page check for the cookie and maintain the session on the cookies basis